# Controlling PC loudness via Android

Tags: android

I want to create an intent on an android phone that sets (or increases/decreases) the loudness of music that gets played on a PC running Windows.
Is there some API that helps me?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create some type of service on the windows pc that would expose a way for the android device to tell the windows pc to change the volume. there is nothing built in to windows, or android that will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [Gmote](http://www.androidtapp.com/gmote/) that allows remote control of Windows Media Center(WMC). You may use the API of WMC to create your own client if you like.

Comment: Gmote can control the loudness but it doesn't provide me an API out of the box to let my application change the loudness.

Comment: I don't see a way to talk to WMC from an Android app without writing my own copy of Gmote.